# CSS add shadow to angled div

Tags: html, css, shadow

I have the following code:

```css
.angled{
background-color: red;
height: 120px;
width: 100%;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 1600px 0, 1600px 53%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 1600px 0, 1600px 53%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="angled"></div>
```

I want to add an inset shadow to the lower edge of the div. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider a skewed element as a background where you can easily apply an inset shadow:

```css
.angeled {
  position:relative;
  height: 120px;
  overflow:hidden;
  z-index:0;
}
.angeled::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:-20px;
  left:-20px;
  right:-20px;
  bottom:0;
  transform-origin:left;
  transform:skewY(-3deg);
  background:red;
  box-shadow:0 -2px 20px green inset
}
```

```html
<div class="angeled"></div>
```

You can also create this using gradient:

```css
.angeled {
  position:relative;
  height: 120px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(red,red) top/100% 50%,
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,
      red calc(50% - 15px),green calc(50% - 1px),
      transparent 50%) bottom left/150% 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="angeled"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `filter: drop-shadow`. See the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow

```css
.angeled{
background-color: red;
height: 120px;
width: 100%;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 1600px 0, 1600px 53%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 1600px 0, 1600px 53%, 0 100%);
 
}

.outer{
   filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<div class="angeled">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The solution you mentioned doesn't work for my case because I need the shadow to be applied to the **lower** edge.

Comment: Updated. I think that's what you want. You need 2 elements to create a good shadow for a polygon :)

Comment: Go around of the drop-shadow property and have fun, you can appy inner shadow if you want to! But i think you're looking for outer shadow, am i wrong?

Comment: Wrap it with a div overflow hidden, add some padding bottom and you are good to go!

Answer (score 0):

In case you are not bound to using a polygon :)

```css
div.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 150px;
}

div.poly {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #F00;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
  transform: rotate(-2deg) scale(1.2);
  transform-origin: 30px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='poly'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: With some modifications you can implement your approach with one element, https://jsfiddle.net/2stbL0dx/.

Comment: :D nice one! i like it!